# Several virtual computers on the one Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-box

I have a trouble with run several similar virtual machines (computers) on the one Virtual Box (VB). But I can run one virtual machine on the VB.
I use main operation system (OS) is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1, VB (Oracle) v.5.2.6 (Qt5.6.2) and OS of virtual machine is Ubuntu 16.04.
Below I apllicated screenshot with my trouble.

Thank you very much!  [image]

Comment: Off topic, superuser.com is more appropriate.  That said, you can't run virtualbox from within a virtualbox vm.  Other virtualization methods may work, like `kvm`.

Comment: Ok, I have created [branch in the chat](https://superuser.com/questions/1464013/several-virtual-computers-on-the-one-virtual-box). But I don't want run VB from within a VB, I just use one VB and I want run several (two or four) virtual machine in the parallel. I hope for you help, thank you ;-)

Comment: [There is right answer.](https://superuser.com/questions/1464013/several-virtual-computers-on-the-one-virtual-box) Thank everyone!